# How to count the number of times every user has done something?

Tags: ios, swift

The title is worded pretty poorly but hopefully i can explain what i want to do. Say i have an app and in this app i have a 'play' button. Can i count the number of times every user has pressed 'play' and then send this to the website for the app? For example, imagine i owned candy crush and on the website i wanted a counter that read something like '345745646 levels completed', how would i do this? Currently, my app is offline only and does not connect to any server nor to the cloud etc. I also haven't created the website yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, you can look at using something like Parse as a backend for your app if you do not have a lot of experience with server side stuff.

You could create a database table called Action and every time a user hits the play button, create a new Play record in the action table.  To show a counter, you would query the database and get a count of all the play Actions in the Actions table.

Hope that sets you on the right path.